# Install a RPM with all dependencies locally

Tags: centos, rpm

I am trying to install docker-ce on centos 7 using rpm downloaded from the official site, downloaded the dependencies using yum `--downloadonly` in a directory and while trying to install the docker-ce RPM i am told that there are unfulfilled dependencies.

I have two questions about the above

- If / how can a RPM be installed with all its dependencies without
  worrying about the sequence of the dependencies present in the same directory as the main RPM
- Can we download all dependencies for a RPM package and install it without internet / local repo access at all ?

Comment: Are you trying to install the downloaded packages with `rpm`?

Comment: I am trying to install it using ```yum localinstall --disablerepo=*```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after some more hit and trial I was able to install the RPM. Here are the steps I took.

I downloaded the dependencies for the main RPM, on installing the RPMs I was prompted to download a few more packages, downloaded those too and went till there were nothing in the to be downloaded section.

I put all the packages in one directory and did a `yum localinstall *.rpm`.